# Pattern matching with extraction of found substrings to variables

Tags: c#, string, parsing, pattern-matching

I have some strings of some defined format like `Foo.<Whatever>.$(Something)` and I would like to split them in parts and have each part automatically assigned to a variable.

I once wrote something resembling the bash/shell pipe command option '<' with C# classes and operator overloading. The usage was something like

```
ParseExpression ex = pex("item1") > ".<" > pex("item2") > ">.$(" > pex("item3") > ")";
ParseResult r = new ParseResult(ex, "Foo.<Whatever>.$(Something)");
```

`ParseResult` then had a Dictionary with the keys item1 through item3 set to the strings found in the given string. The method `pex` generated some object that could be used with the > operator, eventually having a chain of ParseExpressionParts which constitute a `ParseExpression`.

I don't have the code at hand in the moment, and before I start coding it from scratch again I thought I better ask whether someone has done and published it already.

Comment: This should be doable with a simple regular expression, something along the lines of `^(\w+)\.<(\w+)>\.\$\((\w+)\)$`, which will yield Foo, Whatever and Something as Groups 1, 2 and 3. No parser needed.

Comment: Is there some beautiful library that makes it easier to construct regex expressions something in the form of: `Regex r = RegexBuilder.AnyChar().FollowedBy('<').AnyChar().FollowedBy('>')...` ?

Comment: I would suggest to "bite the bullet" and learn regular expression syntax. Yes, it's a terribly obscure language, but (contrary to other obscure languages) it is immensely useful and (more or less) standardized. It's a one-time investment that will pay off in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with Heinzi's suggestion and eventually came up with the following code:

```
const string tokenPrefix = "px";
const string tokenSuffix = "sx";
const string tokenVar = "var";

string r = string.Format(@"(?<{0}>.*)\$\((?<{1}>.*)\)(?<{2}>.*)",
                         tokenPrefix, tokenVar, tokenSuffix);
Regex regex = new Regex(r);
Match match = regex.Match("Foo$(Something)Else");

if (match.Success)
{
  string prefix = match.Groups[tokenPrefix].Value; // = "Foo"
  string suffix = match.Groups[tokenSuffix].Value; // = "Something"
  string variable = match.Groups[tokenVar].Value;  // = "Else" 
}
```

After talking to a collegue about this I was told to consider using the C# parser coonstruction library named ["Sprache"](https://github.com/sprache/Sprache) (which is something between regex and ANTLR-alike toolsets) when my pattern usage increases and I want to have better maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

The parse expressions remind me of [parser combinators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_combinator)  like  Parsec and FParsec (for F#). How complex is the syntax going to be? As it is, it could be handled by a regex with groups.

If you want to create a more complex grammar using parser combinators you can use [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/), one of the better known parser combinators, targeting F#. In general, functional languages like F# are used a lot in such situations. [CSharp-monad](https://github.com/louthy/csharp-monad) is a parser combinator targeting C#. The project isn't very active though.

You can also use a full-blown parser generator like [ANTLR 4](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25b991db-befd-441b-b23b-bb5f8d07ee9f). ANTLR is used by ASP.NET MVC to parse Razor syntax views. ANTLR 4 creates a parse tree and allows you to use either a Visitor or a Listener to process it that are similar to DOM or SAX processing.. A Listener calls your code as soon as an element is encounter (eg the opening `<`, the content etc), while the visitor works on the finished tree.

The Visual Studio extension for ANTLR will generate both the parser classes as well as base Visitor and Listener classes for your grammar. The NetBeans-based [ANTLRWorks](http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/demo/antlrworks) IDE makes creating and testing grammars very easy.

A rough grammar for your example would be :

```
format: tag '.' '<' category '>' '.' '$' '(' value ')';
tag      : ID;
category : ID;
value    : ID;

ID       :[A-Z0-9]+;
```

Or you could define keywords like `FOO : 'FOO'` that have special meaning for your grammar. A visitor or listener could handle the tag eg to format a string, execute an operation on the values etc.

There are no hard and fast rules. Personally, I use regular expressions for simpler cases, eg processing relatively simple log files and ANTLR for more complex cases like screen-scraping mainframe data. I haven't looked into parser combinators as I never had the time to get comfortable with F#. They would be really handy though to handle some messed up log4net log files